# CSS - Non-overlapping / no-double borders with border-collapse: separate;

Tags: css, border, css-tables, overlap

I need a way to add a non-overlapping / no-double borders in the table (this needs to be a general class using selectors etc):

> http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/X3VMJ/

I need `border-collapse: separate;` because I use border radius on the title stuff (not in example).

`td:first-child` almost works but it adds extra borders in the "bottom info" td (see example)

Adding `td:only-child` along with `td:not([colspan]):first-child` is the best lead I have so far but that still messes up with the "bottom info" td since it only has one thing in it.

I currently am using `td:not([colspan]):first-child` which works great except for the rows with a single cell that are stretched across the whole table with colspan..

Comment: Not sure I see the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not put the `top` and `left` borders on the `table` element and leave those out for cells? Like: http://jsfiddle.net/X3VMJ/6/

Comment: I need to have border-radius on the right and left of the title. I updated the example: http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/X3VMJ/

Comment: @MLM, I haven't cross-browser tested, but it seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/X3VMJ/8/

Comment: Thanks eyelidlessness

Here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/X3VMJ/ -- I am not sure if I should mark this solved.. Since the comment helped and not the reply.. I will add a reply in 3 hours(minimum wait time to reply to own topic) with the proper explanation of it.